# Three errors when using tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, mactex

I am using MacTex 2015 and Texpad as LaTeX editor.
When I try to import the tzik package

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

the following 3 errors appear

[image]

Weird thing though is that everything looks fine in my document.

All my packages are up-to-date as well. Do I have to import other packages? Anybody experienced the same issue?

**A quick doc (thanks to Zarko):**

```
    \documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % A4 paper and 11pt font size
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
    \usepackage{mathtools}  % Math packages
    \usepackage{amsfonts}   % Math packages
    \usepackage{bm}         % Math packages
    \usepackage{array}      % Math packages (and fixed column width)
    \usepackage[UKenglish]{isodate}
    %\cleanlookdateon % Remove ordinal day reference

    \usepackage{secdot}         % section title dots
    \sectiondot{subsection}     % subsection title dots
    \sectiondot{subsubsection}  % subsubsection title dots

    \usepackage{grffile}        % figure names with spaces

    \usepackage{tikz}           % block diagrams & control schemes
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,positioning,calc}

    \usepackage{sectsty}        % Allows customizing section commands
    \allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape} % Make all sections centered, the default font and small caps

    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} %lettere accentate
    \usepackage[boxed,linesnumbered,noresetcount]{algorithm2e}  %algorithms
    %\usepackage{ragged2e}      %\justifying
    \usepackage{subfigure}      % subfigure
    \usepackage{float}          % stuck figures
    \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} %captions in bold
    \usepackage{enumitem}       % nested numbered lists

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Custom headers and footers
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 21mm and 11mm,
        start chain = going right,
        place/.style = {rectangle, draw, thick, minimum size=6mm,
                 on chain}]
        \node[place] (4) {Shrinked Dataset};
        \node[place] (5) {Weighting Features};
        \node[place] (1) {SVM Classifier};
        \node[place] (2) {Model};
        \node[place] (3) [below=of 1] {Performances (fitness) Evaluation};

        \draw[-latex]   (4) edge (5) 
                        (5) edge (1) 
                        (1) edge (2) 
                        (2) edge (3);
        \draw[-latex] (3) -- node[fill=white] {$p_i$} (5);
        \draw[-latex] (3) -- node[fill=white] {$C$ and $\gamma$}  (1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Step \#2 flowchart: SVM tuning with GA. This closed-loop will quit after a given number of generations has been created by the GA.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**The resulting picture:**

[image]

**Error Log:**

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mainCI15.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9o> and hyphenation patterns for 80 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package scrlfile, 2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package typearea, 2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/bm.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/isodate/isodate.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/substr/substr.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/isodate/english.idf
Define commands for English date format
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/secdot/secdot.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grffile.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)))) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty:95: Undefined control sequence.
l.95 \DeclareTextSy

)
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def:113: Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \EveryShipout 

l.113 \EveryShipout
                   {%

/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def:145: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.145 ...box\@cclv \else\hsize=\wd\@cclv \noindent
                                                  \unhbox\@cclv \fi%
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarychains.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sectsty/sectsty.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/utf8x.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucs.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-global.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/relsize/relsize.sty)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show a minimal document that produces the issue?

Comment: Hi @egreg, post edited. Hope this is ok.

Comment: `\usepackage{float}` is missing (needed for the `[H]`) or just drop that `[H]`

Comment: Apart from the one due to `H`, I get no other error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support, I've upgraded the whole packages list. "float" is in it, I have no problem whatsoever with figures

Comment: No error here also with the extended example. My impression is that TeXpad is not very reliable about error messages. Can you look for them in the `.log` file?

Comment: everyshi.sty:95: Undefined control sequence.
l.95 \DeclareTextSy
                   
)
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def:113: Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \EveryShipout

Comment: l.113 \EveryShipout
                   {%

/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def:145: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.145 ...box\@cclv \else\hsize=\wd\@cclv \noindent
                                                  \unhbox\@cclv \fi%

Comment: I had to split this in 2 comments. This is you the log snippet that is pointed to by the error screen. The whole out, as you'd expect, is rather long

Comment: @SpookyKid You should add the error message to your question

Answer (score 2):

Your code for TikZ image has error: you use `\draw [-latex] (4) -> (5);` instead of `\draw [-latex] (4) -- (5);`. Also is missing TikZ library `arrow`. Beside this see, if the next code of images is useful for you:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 21mm and 11mm,
  start chain = going right,
 place/.style = {rectangle, draw, thick, minimum size=6mm,
                 on chain}
                        ]
\node[place] (4) {Shrinked Dataset};
\node[place] (5) {Weighting Features};
\node[place] (1) {SVM Classifier};
\node[place] (2) {Model};
%
\node[place] (3) [below=of 1] {Performances (fitness) Evaluation};
%      
\draw[-latex]   (4) edge (5) 
                (5) edge (1) 
                (1) edge (2) 
                (2) edge (3);
\draw[-latex] (3) -- node[fill=white] {$p_i$} (5);
\draw[-latex] (3) -- node[fill=white] {$C$ and $\gamma$}  (1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

It need Tikz libraries `chains` and `positioning`, i.e. in preamble you need to add `\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,positioning}`. Above code gives:

[image]

Other remarks to your MWE you can find in comments above.

Comment: Thank you Zarko, this looks absolutely smarter than mine. Although these 3 errors are still there.

Comment: I generate my image with code you provided in your edited question. I compile it without any problem (on W10 machine, 64-bit MikTeX). Anyway, if you already use my code, it would be nice to (at least) vote my answer :-)

Comment: Dear Zarko, thank you very much indeed for your help. As soon as I get 15 rep points, I most certainly will vote your answer ;)

Comment: Maybe will help if you erase aux and log file and than try to compile again. And as pointed egreg in his comment, your TeXpad is not very reliable.